# C1083 WIN32 No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Visual Studio C++ 2008

I have downloaded a sample project.

I converted the project from VS 7 to VS 9.

However, when I compile I get this error:

```
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'WIN32': No such file or directory
```

Under project properties > preprocessor definitions. I have WIN32 defined there.

I have never had this error before.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: @robUK, check the MSDN site for info about the [Error C1083](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et4zwx34%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Project-->Properties-->C/C++-->General-->Additional include** directories and make sure no **WIN32** chars.

Make sure **PATH** environement variable values that doesn't exist **WIN32** chars.